# numpy.where with two-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

One can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for selecting values from two arrays depending on a condition:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(5)
b = numpy.random.rand(5)
c = numpy.where(a > 0.5, a, b)  # okay
```

If the array has more dimensions, however, this does not work anymore:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
b = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
c = numpy.where(a[:, 0] > 0.5, a, b)  # !
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 10, in <module>
    c = numpy.where(a[:, 0] > 0.5, a, b)  # okay
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in where
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,2) (5,2)
```

I would have expected a numpy array of shape `(5,2)`.

What's the issue here? How to work around it?

Comment: why don't you use `c = numpy.where(a > 0.5, a, b)`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that broadcasting in `numpy` only works from the right, so while `(5,)` shaped arrays can broadcast with `(2,5)` shaped arrays they can't broadcast with `(5,2)` shaped arrays.  to broadcast with a `(5,2)` shaped array you need to maintain the second dimension so that the shape is `(5,1)` (anything can broadcast with `1`)

Thus, you need to maintain the second dimension when indexing it (otherwise it removes the indexed dimension when only one value exists).  You can do this by putting the index in a one-element list:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
b = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
c = numpy.where(a[:, [0]] > 0.5, a, b) # works
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c = numpy.where(a > 0.5, a, b)`

however if you want to use  only the first column of `a` then you need to consider the shape of the output.

let's first see what is the shape of this operation

`(a[:, 0] > 0.5).shape`    # outputs (5,)

it's one dimensional

while the shape of a and b is (5, 2)

it's two dimensional and hence you can't broadcast this

the solution is to reshape the mask operation to be of shape (5, 1)

your code should look like this

```
a = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
b = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
c = numpy.where((a[:, 0] > 0.5).reshape(-1, 1), a, b)  # !
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
b = numpy.random.rand(5, 2)
c = numpy.where(a > 0.5, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of: `c = np.where(a>0.5,a,b)`

you can use: `c = np.array([a,b])[a>0.5]`

which works for multidimensional arrays if a and b have the same shape.